# Upload de imagem com ImageMagick

Tags: php, laravel, upload, imagemagick

Usando a biblioteca `Imagick`, é possível carregar uma imagem vinda diretamente do formulário de *upload*? Ou seja, sem precisar primeiro movê-la para uma pasta e especificar o caminho no `Imagick`.

Estou tentando dessa forma, mas me retorna o erro `Can not process empty Imagick object`

```
$image = new \Imagick($request->img);
$fileName = date('YmdHis') . microtime(true) . rand(111111111, 999999999) . '.jpg';
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(70);
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
$image->stripImage();
$image->writeImage('uploads/perfil/' . $fileName);
```

Dessa forma, movendo primeiro para uma pasta, está funcionando, mas acredito que tenha uma perda de desempenho já que precisa mover a imagem duas vezes:

```
$file = $request->img;
$fileName = date('YmdHis') . microtime(true) . rand(111111111, 999999999) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->move('uploads/perfil', $fileName);

$image = new \Imagick(public_path('uploads/perfil/' . $fileName));
$image->setImageCompressionQuality(70);
$image->setImageFormat("jpg");
$image->stripImage();
$image->writeImage('uploads/perfil/' . $fileName);
```

Comment: Está usando algum framework?

Comment: Sim, o Laravel.

Comment: Teoricamente é só trocar `$request->img` para `$request->img->path()`. Visto que `$request->img` é uma instância de [`UploadedFile`](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html)

Comment: @fernandosavio Cara, era isso mesmo. Valeu!

Comment: Vou criar uma resposta caso alguém caia aqui do google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teoricamente é só trocar `$request->img` para `$request->img->path()`. Visto que `$request->img` é uma instância de [UploadedFile](https://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.html).